# ¿Qué tecnología ocupar para detectar si un estacionamiento público está ocupado?

Tags: web

Estoy preparando mi tesis y una de mis ideas es crear un sistema de estacionamiento en el que las personas (por ejemplo discapacitados) puedan revisar online qué estacionamientos exclusivos para discapacitados están ocupados en toda la ciudad.

Mi mayor duda es qué tecnología ocupar para detectar que un estacionamiento está ocupado. Debe ser barato y durable ya que esto estaría en la calle donde delincuentes podrían destruirlo o robarlo, y eso debe controlarse. No sé si existe la tecnología para detectar un peso que se ubique debajo del pavimento y este sensor se conecte por 3G para enviar los datos. Eso es lo que se me ocurre a mí.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Tu pregunta está basada en opiniones -algo que no es común- pero admito que estoy interesado en leer algunas respuestas a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

En mi opinión, creo que utilizar [sensores de presión](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_sensor), aplicados a una plataforma ubicada en el suelo/pavimento puede ser la opción más barata y fácilmente aplicable. Los componentes pueden programarse con Arduino para realizar pruebas.

En la siguiente imagen podes ver una aplicación para estos casos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen puedes ver cómo los sensores de presión envían información a centrales Wifi o Infrarrojas, que recolectan los datos y pueden notificar a centrales.

Comment: No entiendo como una opinión tiene votos positivos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar sensores infrarojos o de sonido (ultrasonico) posicionados en la parte superior del estacionamiento, con éstos puedes determinar la distancia de un objeto bajo el sensor, y por tanto determinar si está utilizado.

Los conectas en arreglo y controlas desde una única placa de desarrollo (Arduino, raspberry, etc), que tenga conexión a la red ( internet de las cosas). Es Ultra económico y de fácil reemplazo en caso de robo o deterioro.

Además estas placas pueden ser potenciadas con poca corriente, por lo que incluso puedes potenciarlos por panel solar. que cargue una bateria para dar autonomía en la noche.

saludos